# Why doesn't the rotation matrix rotate in the center of the text?

Tags: c, opengl, matrix, rotation

I am trying to rotate a text in OpenGL, but however, the problem is that the text rotates like it should but in the wrong point i.e, it does not rotate at the center of the text(and by that I want to know how I could do that!).

The reason I am confused because I am using multiple texture for different letters of the text which makes me confused.

If you are wondering which library I'm using, it is [CGLM](https://github.com/recp/cglm)

But when I compile this code the rotate function rotates the object with the wrong point of rotation.

According to Rabbid76. I did the following to get the size of the whole text:-

```
for (int i = 0; i < (signed)strlen(text); i++)
{
    tw += iterator[(int)text[i]].Character_Array.Size[0];
    th += iterator[(int)text[i]].Character_Array.Size[1];
}
```

Still I am not getting the proper result, the text is still misplaced.

Before any rotation(this is where IT SHOULD rotate):-
[image: Before rotation]
After 45 degrees rotation(it gets misplaced from its position):-
[image: After rotation]

Edit: The whole code of the source file:-

```
// Std. Includes
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
// GLEW
#define GLEW_STATIC
#include <GL/glew.h>
// GLFW
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
// GLM
#include <cglm/cglm.h>
// FreeType
#include <ft2build.h>
#include FT_FREETYPE_H

// Properties
const GLuint WIDTH = 800, HEIGHT = 600;

const GLchar * vertexShaderSource =
    "#version 330 core\n"
    "layout(location = 0) in vec4 vertex;\n"
    "out vec2 TexCoords;\n"
    "uniform mat4 projection;\n"
    "uniform mat4 model;\n"
    "void main()\n"
    "{\n"
    "gl_Position = projection * model * vec4(vertex.xy, 0.0, 1.0);\n"
    "TexCoords = vertex.zw;\n"
    "}\n\0";

const GLchar * fragmentShaderSource =
    "#version 330 core\n"
    "in vec2 TexCoords;\n"
    "out vec4 color;\n"
    "uniform sampler2D text;\n"
    "uniform vec4 textColor;\n"
    "void main()\n"
    "{\n"
    "vec4 sampled = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, texture(text, TexCoords).r);\n"
    "color = textColor * sampled;\n"
    "}\n\0";

/// Holds all state information relevant to a character as loaded using FreeType
typedef struct {
    GLuint TextureID;   // ID handle of the glyph texture
    int Size[2];    // Size of glyph
    int Bearing[2];  // Offset from baseline to left/top of glyph
    GLuint Advance;    // Horizontal offset to advance to next glyph
} Character;

typedef struct
{
    GLchar char_Array;
    Character Character_Array;
} Iterator;

Iterator * iterator;

GLuint VAO, VBO;
// RenderText function.. to render our text...
void RenderText(GLuint program, const char * text, GLfloat originx, GLfloat originy, GLfloat x, GLfloat y, GLfloat scalex, GLfloat scaley, float rotation, float r, float g, float b, float a);

// The MAIN function, from here we start our application and run the Game loop
int main()
{
    iterator = NULL;
    // Init GLFW
    glfwInit();
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GL_FALSE);

    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(WIDTH, HEIGHT, "LearnOpenGL", NULL, NULL); // Windowed
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    // Initialize GLEW to setup the OpenGL Function pointers
    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
    glewInit();

    // Define the viewport dimensions
    glViewport(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);

    // Set OpenGL options
    glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

    // Compile and setup the shader
    GLuint vertex_shader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(vertex_shader, 1, &vertexShaderSource, NULL);
    glCompileShader(vertex_shader);
    GLuint fragment_shader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(fragment_shader, 1, &fragmentShaderSource, NULL);
    glCompileShader(fragment_shader);
    GLuint program = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(program, vertex_shader);
    glAttachShader(program, fragment_shader);
    glLinkProgram(program);
    glDeleteShader(vertex_shader);
    glDeleteShader(fragment_shader);

    mat4 projection;
    glm_ortho(0.0f, (GLfloat)WIDTH, (GLfloat)HEIGHT, 0.0f, -1, 1, projection);
    glUseProgram(program);
    glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(program, "projection"), 1, GL_FALSE, (GLfloat *)projection);

    // FreeType
    FT_Library ft;
    // All functions return a value different than 0 whenever an error occurred
    if (FT_Init_FreeType(&ft))
        printf("ERROR::FREETYPE: Could not init FreeType Library\n");

    // Load font as face
    FT_Face face;
    if (FT_New_Face(ft, "playfair.ttf", 0, &face))
        printf("ERROR::FREETYPE: Failed to load font\n");

    // Set size to load glyphs as
    FT_Set_Pixel_Sizes(face, 0, 72);

    // Disable byte-alignment restriction
    glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);

    int i = 0;
    // Load first 128 characters of ASCII set
    for (GLubyte c = 0; c < 255; c++)
    {
        // Load character glyph 
        if (FT_Load_Char(face, c, FT_LOAD_RENDER))
        {
            printf("ERROR::FREETYTPE: Failed to load Glyph\n");
            continue;
        }
        // Generate texture
        GLuint texture;
        glGenTextures(1, &texture);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
        glTexImage2D(
            GL_TEXTURE_2D,
            0,
            GL_RED,
            face->glyph->bitmap.width,
            face->glyph->bitmap.rows,
            0,
            GL_RED,
            GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
            face->glyph->bitmap.buffer
        );
        // Set texture options
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
        // Now store character for later use
        Character character = {
            texture,
            {(signed)face->glyph->bitmap.width, (signed)face->glyph->bitmap.rows},
            {face->glyph->bitmap_left, face->glyph->bitmap_top},
            (GLuint)face->glyph->advance.x
        };
        iterator = (Iterator*)realloc(iterator, sizeof(Iterator) * (i + 1));
        iterator[i].Character_Array = character;
        iterator[i].char_Array = c;
        i++;
    }
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
    // Destroy FreeType once we're finished
    FT_Done_Face(face);
    FT_Done_FreeType(ft);


    // Configure VAO/VBO for texture quads
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
    glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);
    glBindVertexArray(VAO);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(GLfloat) * 6 * 4, NULL, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 4 * sizeof(GLfloat), 0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    glBindVertexArray(0);

    glfwVulkanSupported();
    // Game loop
    float k = 0;
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        // Check and call events
        glfwPollEvents();

        // Clear the colorbuffer
        glClearColor(0.2f, 0.3f, 0.3f, 1.0f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        if (k > 360)
        {
            k = 0;
        }
        k += 0.1f;
        RenderText(program, "Rotation", 0, 0, 10.0f, 10.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, k, 0.5f, 0.8f, 0.2f, 1.0f);

        // Swap the buffers
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
    }

    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}

void RenderText(GLuint program, const char * text, GLfloat originx, GLfloat originy, GLfloat x, GLfloat y, GLfloat scalex, GLfloat scaley, float rotation, float r, float g, float b, float a)
{
    // Activate corresponding render state  
    glUseProgram(program);
    glUniform4f(glGetUniformLocation(program, "textColor"), r, g, b, a);
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glBindVertexArray(VAO);

    GLfloat tw = iterator[(int)text[i]].Character_Array.Bearing[0],
        th = 0.0f;
    for (int i = 0; i < (signed)strlen(text); i++)
    {
        Character ch = iterator[(int)text[i]].Character_Array;
        tw += (ch.Advance >> 6);
        th += ch.Size[1];
    }

    GLfloat rx = tw / 2.0f;
    GLfloat ry = th / 2.0f;

    mat4 model;
    glm_mat4_identity(model);

    glm_translate(model, (vec3) { originx, originy, 0.0f });

    glm_translate(model, (vec3) { scalex * rx, scaley * ry, 0.0f });
    glm_rotate(model, glm_rad(rotation), (vec3) { 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f });
    glm_translate(model, (vec3) { -scalex * rx, -scaley * ry, 0.0f });

    glm_scale(model, (vec3) { scalex, scaley, 1.0f });

    GLfloat xpos = 0.0;
    GLfloat ypos = 0.0;
    for (int i = 0; i < (signed)strlen(text); i++)
    {
        Character ch = iterator[(int)text[i]].Character_Array;

        mat4 ch_model;
        memcpy(ch_model, model, 16 * sizeof(float));
        glm_translate(ch_model, (vec3) { x, 0.0f, 0.0f });

        // Now advance cursors for next glyph (note that advance is number of 1/64 pixels)
        x += (ch.Advance >> 6); // Bitshift by 6 to get value in pixels (2^6 = 64 (divide amount of 1/64th pixels by 64 to get amount of pixels))

        glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(program, "model"), 1, GL_FALSE, (GLfloat *)ch_model);

        // Render glyph texture over quad
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, ch.TextureID);

        GLfloat w = ch.Size[0] * scalex;
        GLfloat h = ch.Size[1] * scaley;
        GLfloat vertices[6][4] = {
            { 0.0f,  h,     0.0, 1.0 },
            { w,     0.0f,  1.0, 0.0 },
            { 0.0f,  0.0f,  0.0, 0.0 },

            { 0.0f,  h,     0.0, 1.0 },
            { w,     h,     1.0, 01.0 },
            { w,     0.0f,  01.0, 0.0 },
        };

        // Update content of VBO memory
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
        glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, sizeof(vertices), vertices); // Be sure to use glBufferSubData and not glBufferData
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
        // Render quad
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
    }
    glBindVertexArray(0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`glm_rotate` applies rotation at origin. So if your **geometry's center** is not at the origin then rotation will not made around center of object/geometry.

Solution:  **X = T(p)Rz(φ)T(−p)** where X is final transform, p is pivot

1. Translate pivot (or object center, not object's position, it is not same) to origin
2. Apply Rotation or scaling
3. Translate pivot back to it's original position

If you want to rotate around center of object (if object's center is not at the origin) then you must compute center of that object/geometry. Before apply any rotation. You could compute bounding box then get center of that box.

[**cglm**](http://github.com/recp/cglm) also provides functions for that: `glm_vec_center(min, max, pivot); /* pivot = center of object */`. Now we have center point. Let's rotate around that point:

```
/* ... */

glm_vec_center(min, max, pivot); /* center of object */
glm_vec_inv_to(pivot, pivotInv); /* -pivot */

/* ... */

glm_translate(model, pivot);
glm_rotate(model, angle, axis);
glm_translate(model, pivotInv);
```

The code above do same thing as **X = T(p)Rz(φ)T(−p)** (translate(-pivot), rotate, translate(pivot)). The order seems reverse in code because `glm_translate` = Transform * Translate. It would not be reverse order if `glm_translate` = Translate * Transform. cglm may provide this alternative translation multiplication too in the future

**EDIT:** By starting v0.4.2 version [**cglm**](http://github.com/recp/cglm) provides functions for this purpose: check [glm_rotate_at()](http://cglm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/affine.html#c.glm_rotate_at) and [glm_quat_rotate_at()](http://cglm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quat.html#c.glm_quat_rotate_at), `glm_rotate_atm` and `glm_quat_rotate_atm` creates NEW rotations for pivot point since `glm_rotate_at` and `glm_quat_rotate_at` rotates existing transforms. To use these functions make sure you have latest version.

Comment: Thanks!, but I already found out the answer! I used translation to move the object minus the origin and then scale and rotate from there. But thanks anyway! I will take you answer as the correct answer because it is also a good and clever way to do it (I didn't know about it!)